# Extract text from string Java

Tags: java

With this string "ADACADABRA". how to extract "CADA" From string "ADACADABRA" in java.

and also how to extract the id  between  "/" and "?" from the link below.

http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zaaU9lJ34c5?rel=0

output should be: zaaU9lJ34c5

but should use "/" and "?" in the process.

Comment: If it so easy, what have you tried?

Comment: how does this even make sense? If you know you've to extract "CADA", you already have that String? why extract it from somewhere?

Comment: In what way exactly ? as a substring ? can the input string vary ?

Comment: refer to my updated question please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
and also how to extract the id between "/" and "?" from the link below.

http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zaaU9lJ34c5?rel=0

output should be: zaaU9lJ34c5
```

Should be :

```
String url = "http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zaaU9lJ34c5?rel=0";
String str = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.indexOf("?"));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  String s = "ADACADABRA";
  String s2 = s.substring(3,7);
```

Here 3 specifies the beginning index, and 7 specifies the stopping point.
The string returned contains all the characters from the beginning index, up to, but not including, the ending index.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by extract, so I've provided the code to remove it from the String, I'm not certain if this is what you want.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        String string = "ADACADABRA";
        string = string.replace("CADA", "");
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is untested but something like this may help for the youtube part:

```
     String youtubeUrl = "http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zaaU9lJ34c5?rel=0";

     String[] urlParts = youtubeUrl.split("/");

     String videoId = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

     videoId = videoId.substring(0, videoId.indexOf("?"));
```

Extracting CADA from the string makes no sense. You will need to specify how you have determined that CADA is the string to extract.

E.g. is it because it is the middle 4 characters? Is it because you are stripping off 3 characters each side? Are you just looking for the String "CADA"? Is it characters 3,7 of the String? Is it the first 4 of the last 7 characters of a String? Is it because it contains 2 vowels and 2 consanants? I could go on..

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "CADA";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher m = p.matcher(originalText);
while (m.find()) {
    String outputThis = m.group(1);
}
```

Use this tool http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you don't take in account the fact of `java.lang.String` immutability. That's why you need to assign the result of substringing to a new variable.