# How to extract two lines of text from a 10lines text paragraph?

Tags: java

I have 10lines of text,of those,only two lines I need rest not needed,,these two lines left side has name as scannable IDs and on Right the value will be generated randomly,,,so I want this and remove the rest text

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
.
.
.
Scannable I'd:AGD364748HDBD
.
Name : provision
.
Line 10
```

The above two lines I need them as output and the right hand side if the two lines after colon: are randomly generated,I need those too..

Can someone help me?

Comment: Share the relevant `HTML` and your code trials.

Comment: This is `Pure Java` concept why `Selenium` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text from string Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154387/extract-text-from-string-java)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the method:

```
lines = text.split("\n");
```

It returns an array of lines and after:

```
text = lines.get(0) + lines.get(1);
```

Comment: Is there any other way where we can just extract those two lines,,,like say string starting with or any other way

Comment: Sorry but I don't know, why you don't use this method?